# Использование PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, java

Не особо понимаю как пользоваться `PreferenceFragment` вместе с обычным окном (допустим `MainActivity`). Вопрос вызывает то как вызвать `PreferenceFragment` из `MainActivity`? вроде пользоваться `PreferenceFragment` нужно также как и `PreferenceActivity`. Проблем с изучением `PreferenceActivity` не возникало, там всё просто - в `MainActivity` получил `DefaultSharedPrefs`, и запускай через `Intnet PreferenceActivtiy`... Однако как поступать с фрагментами не понимаю. Вижу два выхода:

1. при клике на определенную кнопочку нужно создавать отдельное новое Активити (унаследованное от `Activity`) и ему назначать в качестве контента `PrefereceFragment`.
2. при клике на кнопку новое Активити не создавать, а скрывать текущий контент и зaменять его методом `FragmentTransaction.replace` на новый `PreferenceFragment`. но этот способ правда сработает если в вызвавшей Активности в конейнере отсутствуют элементы `View`.

...
Так вот. Как мне быть? Каким способом пользоваться? Может быть есть ещё способы?

Comment: Дак делай через fragment.replace в чем проблема ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

здесь [Урок 111. Android 3. Fragments. PreferenceFragment - настройки. Headers](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/181-urok-111-android-3-fragments-preferencefragment-nastrojki-headers.html) детально описаны ответы на Ваши вопросы.

Comment: изза прочтения этого урока мой вопрос как раз и возник.

Comment: я бы создавал отдельное активити.

Comment: понятно. тогда зачем нужен этот PreferenceFragment? если можно сразу но нажатию на кнопку запустить PrefenceActivity минуя фрагмент ?

Comment: например, можно делать вкладки.